# How to save data for SQL Server to XML file

Tags: sql-server, xml, vb.net

I have a project in VB and a function that returns data from SQL Server. The data is saved in a variable. I need to insert the data directly to XML file.

I need vb. code/ script that will save the data to a XML file.

How can I save data from a table in SQL Server into a XML file?

Can anyone send me code to save data from SQL Server to XML file in VB, I have never done this before and I don' have any ideas how to do it.

[It should be something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xc6Ed.png) 
The problem is that I don't know how to write " `-<CON xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">`" at the beginning of the file

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

---

**Update**

This is what I try and it works, the problem is that The problem is that I don't know how to write " `-<CON xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">`" at the beginning of the file. Like I said before.

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim connetionString As String
        Dim connection As SqlConnection
        Dim adapter As SqlDataAdapter
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim sql As String

        connetionString = "Data Source=local\SQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=**;Integrated Security=True"
        connection = New SqlConnection(connetionString)
        sql = "select * from Users"
        Try
            connection.Open()
            adapter = New SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection)
            adapter.Fill(ds)
            connection.Close()
            ds.WriteXml("Product.xml")
            MsgBox("Done")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)


        End Try

    End Sub
```

Comment: We'd be happy to help you troubleshoot code that you write and are stuck with.  But this is not a code generating service.

Comment: Considering, according to your "question" you're already getting the data from SQL Server into VB, and I *assume* in XML format, then the only step you appear to be missing is getting that data from your variable in VB to the file on the storage system. There are plenty of examples on this site, and many others, on how to create a file and amend the contents of an existing file. I'd suggest using yoru favourite search engine to search something like "Store Variable contents in file VB.Net", and you'll probably find 100's of answers.

Answer (score 0):

Using Xml linq the code would look like this

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim xml As String =
            "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" ?>" & _
            "<CON" & _
            " xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema""" & _
            " xmlns:xsi=""http://www.we.org/2001/XMLScehma-instance"">" & _
            "</CON>"


        Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Parse(xml)
        Dim con As XElement = doc.Root
        Dim ds As New DataSet '' this is your dataset from the database

        For Each row As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).AsEnumerable()
            Dim referena As XElement = New XElement("Referenza", New Object() { _
                    New XElement("ConNumOrd", row.Field(Of String)("ConNumOrd")), _
                    New XElement("ConDat", row.Field(Of String)("ConDat")), _
                    New XElement("ConOra", row.Field(Of String)("ConOra")) _
                    })
            con.Add(referena)
        Next row
        doc.Save("filename")
    End Sub

End Module
```